# show category in woocommerce

Tags: categories, plugins

This code show tags from a specific category such as id = 3. I want to make  automatically check which category I am. Can someone please help me ?

```
$args = array('categories'=> '3'); 
$tags = get_category_tags($args); 
$content .= "<ul>"; 
foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
    $content .= "<li><a href=\"$tag->tag_link\">$tag->tag_name</a></li>";
} 
$content .= "</ul>"; 
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within a category you can use [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to get data on the current category.

```
$current_category = get_queried_object();
$args = array( 'categories' => $current_category->term_id ); 
$tags = get_category_tags( $args );
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not working on single product page any idea?

Comment: I solve the problem for single page:  `<?php if ( is_singular('product') ) {
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
?> `

Comment: @Dime Please add that as separate answer.